# Getting positions of your portfolio using python ibPy library

Tags: python, interactive-brokers, ibpy

I am using ibpy to get the positions of my portfolio. I understand that I can do:

```
from ib.opt import ibConnection
tws = ibConnection( host = 'localhost',port= 7496, clientId = 123)
tws.reqAccountUpdates(True,'accountnumber')
```

and then I am supposed to use `updatePortfolio()` in some way, but I don't know how.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

`tws.reqAccountUpdates(True,'accountnumber')`  Will send the string "acctnumber" when you probably meant it to be a variable.  Notice the string I send is my actual (fake)account number.

Then you need to register a callback for the messages you're interested in.

```
from ib.opt import ibConnection, message

def acct_update(msg):
    print(msg)


con = ibConnection(clientId=1)
con.register(acct_update,
             message.updateAccountValue,
             message.updateAccountTime,
             message.updatePortfolio)
con.connect()
con.reqAccountUpdates(True,'DU000000')

#don't forget to disconnect somehow when done
#con.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 2):

There's also `reqPositions()` which as the name implies gives you your positions (and only your positions as opposed to giving you a lot of other info as well). They will be returned in `message.position` messages.